# How do I create a child window inside another program with an OpenGL canvas?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am developing a plug-in in C++ inside a 3rd party program and need to display a window with OpenGL. I want to program in Win32 directly (ie. not use MFC or other wrappers).

I downloaded [NeHes Win32 tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/) and compiled and ran it succesfully on my machine.

However this is a main program that loops and calls PeekMessage and then TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage if there was any message and redraws the OpenGL if not.

I want to "spawn-off" a Win32 OpenGL window and then return control to the 3rd party program:

```
void DisplayOpenGLWindow_ButtonPressed() {
 CreateWindowEx(...);
 InitOpenGL(...);
 return;
}
```

But how do I get the new window to redraw the OpenGL scene?
I tried to add a call to redraw OpenGL inside the callback function:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
   DrawGLScene();   
   return 0;
}
```

But this is not working;
the window is all white even if the clear color is black. Resizing and moving the window does not help.

Comment: Thanks fen! Looks like a good start.

Comment: Why do you not want to use any wrappers? I **strongly** recommend using [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org) or some equivalent to do this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be quite large, so I direct you to some tutorials instead :)

links:

- [OpenGL MFC AppWizard](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32575/OpenGL-MFC-AppWizard)
- [OpenGL Windows GUI Application - songho](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_mvc.html)

Nehe uses Win32 api mostly, so for look for MFC tutorials/articles instead.

Another thing: try to fucus on modern opengl, version 3. and above.